# dust.js include partitial without trimming

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I am using dust.js template engine. The main template includes a partial and the problem is that dust.js trims every line of the included template file.

For example, the main template is:

```
<h1>{header}</h1>
{>dust_cnt /}
```

The dust_cnt.dust is:

```
<div>
  This is
  the content
</div>
```

And I render the response by:
    res.render('dust_template.dust', {header: 'TEST OK'});

The problem that there is no space between `This is` and `the content` in the output. So the output looks like:

```
TEST OK

This isthe content
```

**I can't change all the contents by putting {~n}** or another separator and I don't think there is any reason to do that.

On http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/ I found the following remark `GH- 166 - Added trimming of white spaces in dust templates configuration in the dust.compile ( default option is still true)`. But can't find the way to set set the options to avoid the trimming?

How can I make dust.js to render it the way I expect (with the spaces)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here's issue 166: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/pull/166 you can see that the new, third parameter to `compile` is `strip` and you can pass `false` there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution :). After digging in the source code + checking the issues on the dust's GitHub I decided to use the following to prevent the formatting of the template's nodes:

```
dust.optimizers.format = function(ctx, node) { return node };
```

(Also on https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#controlling-whitespace-suppression)

The default behavior is very dangerous - as it mentioned on the GitHub it can cause serious problems, for example:

```
<script>
//this will alert "test"
alert("this is test");
</script>
```

Will be rendered as:

```
<script>//this will alert "test" alert("this is test");</script>
```

Comment: Wow, unbelievable default behavior.  Thanks for the detective work.  Surprised if this doesn't hit a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange and I understand that you don't want to edit your template files. However, you can workaround this in a less ugly way by adding a space at the end of the line:

```
<div>
  This is < add space here
  the content
</div>
```

Just for the case you cannot find a real solution for this.

Comment: As I told before I can't change every line of every content template, but thank you for your efforts.

Comment: One thing to be aware of with adding the extra space as the solution is some editors may have an option turned on to trim all trailing whitespace on save, which would wreak destruction on any files that rely on a trailing space.